# lodash - remove array of object by it value

Tags: lodash

Using `lodah` - how to remove the object by it's value?

here is my try:

```
var array = ['Education', 'Medicine'];

values = [
    {
      "Category":"Medicine"
    },

    {
      "Category":"Medicine"
    },
    {
      "Category":"Development"
    },
    {
      "Category":"Education"
    }
  ]

  const x = _.without(values, array);
```

console.log(x); expected value is :

```
values = [{
  "Category":"Development"
},]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.differenceWith()` to remove items with a `Category` that exists in the array.

```js
const array = ['Education', 'Medicine'];

const values = [{"Category":"Medicine"},{"Category":"Medicine"},{"Category":"Development"},{"Category":"Education"}];

const result = _.differenceWith(values, array, (o, category) => o.Category === category);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: - how to get the values as included only, opposite of current function? I tried `o.Category !== category` - but not works

Comment: Use intersectionWith instead of differenceWith.

Comment: `intersectionWith ` - is not taking array of values at present it takes one last value as `Medicine`

Comment: Interesting, it seems like a glitch in intersectionWith. The number of results is limited by the 2nd array. In that case you can use @cocoder's answer with `!array.includes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think use lodash is better.
You can use es6 to solve it.

```
result = values.filter(x => array.includes(x.Category));
```